# How to get C++ build command from vcxproj via a C# program

Tags: c#, c++, build, c-preprocessor, vcxproj

I have a Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project object on a specific project.
I have set the correct global properties, according to the build i need.

Is there a way to retrieve programmatically the actual command line which will be used when building?

I will explain a bit what i need, and maybe you will have a different suggestion:
I want to get the preprocessed data from c/cpp file, and since there may be many includes and other stuff in the command line, which i have no information about, which will effect the output itself, I thought of taking the command line and just adding the preprocess flag.

Comment: XY problem, of course. You want "precompiled data" (huh?) and you think you've got a method to get that data via the build, except that you don't have that either. Stop, rethink from the original problem, then specify clearly _what_ you want. ("precompiled" in VC++ refers to a single precompiled header, canonically named ` `stdafx.h`)

Comment: I meant preprocessed. Fixed in original question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the underlying question: set `VCCLCompilerTool.GeneratePreprocessedFile` to `preprocessYes`.

`.KeepComments` may be useful.